# How to hide first column of datagridview add still get data

Tags: css, asp.net, gridview

I want to hide the first column of my gridview with css but am not successful.

[image: Column to hide]

Here is part of the html that is generated.

```
<table class="mGrid" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" rules="all" ridlines="None" border="1" id="PageContent_gvLocation" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
        <tbody><tr>
            <th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$PageContent$gvLocation','Sort$ubicacion_componente_id')">ubicacion id</a></th><th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$PageContent$gvLocation','Sort$armario')">Armario</a></th><th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$PageContent$gvLocation','Sort$cajon')">Cajon</a></th><th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>
                            <span id="PageContent_gvLocation_lblLocationID_0" class="gridTextbox">46</span>
                        </td><td>
                            <span id="PageContent_gvLocation_lblCloset_0" class="gridTextbox">testarmariio</span>
                        </td><td>                       
                            <span id="PageContent_gvLocation_lblDrawer_0" class="gridTextbox">testcajon</span>
                        </td><td>
                            <input type="image" name="ctl00$PageContent$gvLocation$ctl02$ctl00" title="Edit" src="../Images/edit.png" style="height:20px;width:20px;">
                            <input type="image" name="ctl00$PageContent$gvLocation$ctl02$ctl01" title="Delete" src="../Images/delete.png" style="height:20px;width:20px;">
                        </td>
        </tr><tr class="alt">
            <td>
```

Here is my asp.net code.

```
  <asp:GridView ID="gvLocation" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowFooter="true" 
            ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" AllowPaging="True" OnPageIndexChanging="gvLocation_PageIndexChanging"
            OnRowEditing="gvLocation_RowEditing" OnRowCancelingEdit="gvLocation_RowCancelingEdit"
            AllowSorting="true" onsorting="gvLocation_Sorting" ridLines="None" CssClass="mGrid" PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt" CellPadding="3">
            <%-- Theme Properties --%>
            <Columns>  
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ubicacion id" SortExpression="ubicacion_componente_id">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label CssClass="gridTextbox" ID="lblLocationID"  Text='<%# Eval("ubicacion_componente_id") %>' runat="server" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox CssClass="gridTextbox" ID="txtLocationID" Text='<%# Eval("ubicacion_componente_id") %>' runat="server" />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox CssClass="gridTextbox" ID="txtLocationIDFooter" runat="server" />
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>  
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

How can I hide the first column of my gridview using css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to implement only in CSS according to your code, you can try following

```
table.mGrid  tr td:first-child{
   display:none;
}

table.mGrid  tr th:first-child{
   display:none;
}
```

Pager is generally available in last row, you can always have option to exclude last row of the table, use following code :

```
table.mGrid tr:not(:last-child) td:first-child {
    display: none;
}

table.mGrid tr:not(:last-child) th:first-child {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Yes a css solution would be great however when I use the css which you are suggesting it removes the pages numbers at the bottom of my gridview.

Comment: Please post your generated html including pager